# Saving UIImage as Blob SQLite

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, uiimage

I have the following code that pushes information to a database. It gives a successful insert but the "canvas" column (the one that contains the image blob) is NULL. I have modeled my use of sqlite3_prepare_v2 and sqlite3_bind_blob after other answers that I've been looking at on StackOverflow.

```
-(void) sendMoment: (Album *) alb moment:(Moment *) m
{
    @try {
        NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        // First, test for existence of writable file:
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"pictures.sqlite"];

        BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
        if (!success){
            // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
            NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"pictures.sqlite"];
            success = [fileMgr copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
            if (!success) {
                NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
        }

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
        NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate: m.timestamp];

        //add passed-in moment to the given album
        sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([m.moment firstObject], 1.0);


        NSString *deleteSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM MomentTbl WHERE user = \"t-amkruz\""];

        NSString *momentInsertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO MomentTbl (momentID, albumID, title, timestamp, author, latitude, longitude, canvas) VALUES (NULL, %d, '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', ?)", alb.ID, alb.title, dateString, @"user", m.latitude, m.longitude];
        const char *query_stmt = [momentInsertSQL UTF8String];
        const char *dbPath = [writableDBPath UTF8String];

        int result = sqlite3_open(dbPath, &db);

        if (SQLITE_OK == result) {
            char *errInfo = nil;

            sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query_stmt, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL);

            sqlite3_bind_blob(sqlStatement, 1, [imageData bytes], [imageData length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

            result = sqlite3_exec(db, query_stmt, nil, nil, &errInfo);
            if (SQLITE_OK == result) {
                NSLog(@"Sucessful insert");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Insert failed");
            }
            sqlite3_close(db);
        }

        else {
            NSLog(@"Could not open database");
        }

    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"An exception occured: %@", [exception reason]);
    }
}
```

Again, the only part that I have any problems with is the last column; values from every other column insert correctly. I've verified that  `imageData` is non-`nil`. The prepare_v2 statement and the bind_blob statement both return 0 when I check them with NSLog. I would really appreciate help!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I needed to replace the exec statement (and subsequent if statement) with the following:

```
if(sqlite3_step(sqlStatement) == SQLITE_OK){
    NSLog(@"Sucessful insert");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Insert failed");
}
```

Hope this helps someone else.